# After open new form from the main form how to stay in this form after error

Tags: c#, winforms

I have application and from the main form i open new form:

```
Form2 frm2= new Form2(file);
frm2.ShowDialog();
```

And read parameter from user input:

```
TextBox tbInsert;

private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(tbInsert.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        return;
    }
}
```

My problem is that if not legal `IP Address` specified, after the `MessageBox error` `Form2` close and return to the `Main Form` instead of stay in `Form2`

Comment: Why you are using `return;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably made the "btnPlay" button the Form.AcceptButton of your form so that it behaves like an OK buton, pressing the Enter key closes the dialog.  Or you set the button's DialogResult property.  Either way, the dialog automatically closes, the DialogResult property is automatically set.

So you'll have to reset it again to keep the dialog open:

```
try
{
    // etc...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if I guess  correctly  your button was set to return a `dialog result` type for this reason your form is closed. Try something like this in your form2 constructor

```
btnPlay.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
```